# A doubt about ordinary points of differential equations (linear)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> We say that $x_0$ ( $\neq \infty)$ is an ${\bf ordinary}$ point of
>   linear equation
>
> $$ y^{(n)} + p_{(n-1)}(x) y^{(n-1)} + ... + p_1(x) y' + p_0 y = 0 $$
>
> if the coeficient functions of $p_0,..,p_{n-1}$ are all analytic in a
>   neighborhood of $x_0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Now, I have a doubt about the differential equation $y' = |x| y $

Then, we see that the only point where there can be no derivative is $x = 0$, so isnt is true that this equation has all ordinary points except $x_0 = 0$?

My book says on the other hand that the equaiont has no ordinary points because |x| is nowhere analytic.

What is it that am I missing here?

Comment: By analytic do they mean complex analytic?